# How to fix Error 404: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

So I'm new to servlets and jsp, and was following along to the Hello World post-process example from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info. When I tried to run it using Tomcat v9.0 in Eclipse, I get

[image]

After doing some additional research, and poking around, I haven't found a working solution or an explanation of what is happening. I had basically copied the code from the example, so I'm pretty confused as to why it isn't working. I also don't really have the proficiency yet to figure out exactly what is wrong, so any help would be great. My only hunch so far is that I probably messed up the directories or something. Here is a picture:

[image]

The only discrepancy I could find was where my HelloServlet.class was located, which was in

```
 apache-tomcat-9.0.19/webapps/hello/build/classes/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.class
```

instead of

```
/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.class
```

as stated in the example. I assumed this was because Eclipse, by default, had compiled the class file where it is now, but just to be sure, I copied the class folder into WEB-INF so it would match the example, but it still didn't work. So that is where I'm stuck. If anyone could point out my mistake or even help at all, that would be very much appreciated. I have included my hello.jsp, web.xml, and HelloServlet.java files below just in case there's any issues with them.

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Servlet Hello World</title>
        <style>.error { color: red; } .success { color: green; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="hello" method="post">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>
                <label for="name">What's your name?</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.name)}">
                <span class="error">${messages.name}</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="age">What's your age?</label>
                <input id="age" name="age" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.age)}">
                <span class="error">${messages.age}</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit">
                <span class="success">${messages.success}</span>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app 
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0"
  metadata-complete="true">
</web-app>
```

**HelloServlet.java**

```
package com.example.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Preprocess request: we actually don't need to do any business stuff, so just display JSP.
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Postprocess request: gather and validate submitted data and display the result in the same JSP.

        // Prepare messages.
        Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();
        request.setAttribute("messages", messages);

        // Get and validate name.
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        if (name == null || name.trim().isEmpty()) {
            messages.put("name", "Please enter name");
        } else if (!name.matches("\\p{Alnum}+")) {
            messages.put("name", "Please enter alphanumeric characters only");
        }

        // Get and validate age.
        String age = request.getParameter("age");
        if (age == null || age.trim().isEmpty()) {
            messages.put("age", "Please enter age");
        } else if (!age.matches("\\d+")) {
            messages.put("age", "Please enter digits only");
        }

        // No validation errors? Do the business job!
        if (messages.isEmpty()) {
            messages.put("success", String.format("Hello, your name is %s and your age is %s!", name, age));
        }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow cross origin

`private void setAccessControlHeaders(HttpServletResponse resp) {
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9000");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
    }`

Comment: Hi Anil, what exactly do I do with the above function? Do I just it in the HelloServlet class?